# Triggering Primefaces p:selectOneMenu onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2, primefaces

It seems Primefaces `p:selectOneMenu` component wraps the rendered HTML `<select>` tag in a div and shows the selected item as a different label. The changes made by the user are reflected to original `<select>` by javascript I guess, resulting the onchange event binded to `<select>` not to be worked. Thus my following binding of onchange event for all `:input`s is not working for `p:selectOneMenu`s.

```
function applyChangeHandler() {
    $(':input').on('change', function() {
        console.log('on change: ' + this.id);
    });
}
```

However onchange attribute of `p:selectOneMenu` is being fired. So Primefaces triggers this handler under the hood (again I guess).

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="myList" onchange="console.log('selectOneMenu')">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="val1" itemValue="val1"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="val2" itemValue="val2"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

So my requirement is to somehow bind the onchange handler to all `p:selectOneMenu`s from applyChangeHandler() function above. Or it may be triggerred manually with Primefaces specific API or other ways which I expect from you guys to share with. Otherwise a quick workaround will be to use `h:selectOneMenu` instead.

My goal is to detect "unsaved changes on the page". So script above will be placed in a common template as:

```
<p:outputPanel id="sc" autoUpdate="true">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        applyChangeHandler();
    </script>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to provide additional listeners when the framework has already provided you with such?

If your goal is to use jQuery you just put your handler in a js file accessible from the window global scope.

```
function myChangeHandler(that) {
    //wrap the element with jQuery
    var select = jQuery(that);
    //Get the div parent. The actual wrapper of the `selection-menu` widget markup
    var selectMenu = select.parents('div.ui-selectonemenu');
    //From here I can manipulate any HTML child element using jQuery
    jQuery('label.ui-selectonemenu-label', selectMenu).text('mooo');
}
```

Then call your handler `onchange`, passing the `selectOneMenu` as parameter

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="myList" onchange="myChangeHandler(this)">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="val1" itemValue="val1" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="val2" itemValue="val2" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: My goal is to detect "unsaved changes on the page". Therefore the  onchange event is bound to all *:inputs in the page. The script will be placed in a common template. Putting a changehandler to every p:selectOneMenu in all pages is currently less desired.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using onChange, you could utilize "DOMSubtreeModified".

This works for p:selectOneMenu

```
$(".ui-selectonemenu-label").each(function(index) {
    $(this).on("DOMSubtreeModified", setDirty());
});
```

Also. Another possibility if you want the same generic code everywhere is to overwrite the prototype of SelectOneMenu as follows:

```
var origTriggerChange = PrimeFaces.widget.SelectOneMenu.prototype.triggerChange;
// if this code has been run already, don't accumulate triggerChangemethods!
if(origTriggerChange.isModified != "true"){
      PrimeFaces.widget.SelectOneMenu.prototype.triggerChange = function(b){
      this.jq.find("select").change();
      origTriggerChange.call(this, b);
   };
   PrimeFaces.widget.SelectOneMenu.prototype.triggerChange.isModified = "true";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **widgetVar** to **p:selectOneMenu** to play with it in **JS**

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="myList" onchange="console.log('selectOneMenu')" widgetVar="myList">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="val1" itemValue="val1"/>
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="val2" itemValue="val2"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

this Will add this code to you page

```
$(function(){
  PrimeFaces.cw("SelectOneMenu","myList",{
       id:"A2:Form:myList",
       effect:"fade"
  })
});
```

Hope this will help.